# While Generating an upload key keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-upload-key.keystore (Access is denied)

Tags: react-native

While Generating an upload key keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: my-upload-key.keystore (Access is denied)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run CMD as administrator, navigate to the C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin and try to generate upload key again

Answer (score 0):

The `C:\Program Files` directory needs administrator privilege to write, you're storing `.keystore` into it.

Just move to another directory, eg: your workspace dir.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that folder really exist. And after run that with CMD